# How do I freeze a rigid body in its position?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

So, I dropped a suzanne using rigid body physics, I want to freeze it in the pose it landed in and remove the rigid body physics. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the animation to stop at a certain frame, you can for example keyframe the *Dynamic* on option at frame X and keyframe it off at frame X+1:

[image]

If you want to completely remove the action, select the object, go into the header menu > *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes* and choose the frame you want to freeze in the pop-up panel:

[image]

Comment: But I want to save that position and remove the rigid body sim

Comment: ok so does my edit answer?